# How to get the values from a form and prevent submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this simple form:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label for="eName">Name</label>
    <input id="eName" type="text" name="eName">
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input id="Email" type="text"  name="Email">
    <button id="create" class="boton" 
        onclick="doSomething();" type="submit">Create!</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function doSomething() {
    var name, email;
    name = document.getElementById("eName").value;
    email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    putElementsIntoTheDOM(name, email);
}
```

When the user inputs some information I want to populate the DOM with the user input.
The example above works.  But I think it can be done better.  I just don't know how.

How can I wire the `<button>` so that when the user clicks it the form values are passed 
to the function `doSomething()`?

Also, since I'm not sending the form values anywhere except populating the DOM, how can I 
prevent the submission?

I've seen something like this but I can't get it too work.

```
<button id="create" class="boton" onclick="doSomething(this.form);"     
    type="submit">Create!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to update your function declaration to be able to receive the variables you want to send

```
function doSomething(name,email) {
}
```

Secondly, if you have to send values of some fields to that function, you can do so on button click like this.

```
<button id="create" class="boton" onclick="doSomething(document.getElementById('eName').value,document.getElementById('Email').value);" type="submit">Create!</button>
```

However, using unobtrusive javascript is recommended, and for that jQuery is one of the options you can use for  passing variables to your function neatly.

Comment: This answer was flagged by the system as low-quality because of **length** and **content**.  A better answer would explain the key aspects of the code that eluded the OP.

Comment: @EricJ. Thanks for your suggestion, i just did that because OP was almost there, so i thought OP just needed the final push. However i am going to update it to explain the answer as per your advise

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send the form values anywhere, then you just need to remove `type="submit"` from your button.

Your example code works fine. I'm not sure what you mean by a 'better' way. More modern/idiomatic javascript would not be using the `onclick` attribute, but instead binding doSomething to the button. Using jQuery, that would look like:

```
$("#create").click(doSomething);
```

Comment: var create = getElementById("create");  create.addEventListener("onclick", doSomething, false)  Is this what you mean by binding?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the `type="submit"` and `type="button"` that I didn't realize.
Also, the `button` and `submit` types react differently with `onclick` and `onsubmit` events.

For example

```
<form onclick="doSomething()">
<label for="eName">Name</label>
<input id="eName" type="text" name="eName">
<label for="Email">Email</label>
<input id="Email" type="text"  name="Email">
<button id="create" class="boton" type="button">Create!</button>
</form>
```

Notice that at the top of the `form` there is `onclick`.
The `onclick` is fired whenever you focus on an input element, and of course if you click the button.

Changing the form to `<form onsubmit="doSomething();` but not changing the `type="button"` doesn't do anything.  Clicking the button doesn't trigger the function.

By changing the `type="submit"`and keeping the head `<form onsubmit="doSomething();` triggers the function when the button is clicked.  A nice added functionality to this is that if you have any `<input ... required="required">` the `submit` will only work if those fields are filled in (and your form will let you know about the required fields).

To prevent the submission/refreshing (since I'm only populating the DOM with user input) adding `return false` at the form head prevents submission
`<form onsubmit="doSomething(); return false">`.

Finally, to get the form values adding `this`:
`<form onsubmit="doSomething(this); return false>` and then

```
function doSommething(formInfo) {
   var name = formInfo.eName.value;
   var email = formInfo.Email.value;
   ... 
 }
```